# How to send request immediately in WebClient Vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to benchmark my Restful API Server, so I send a ton of request to it to measure throughput and latency. I use Vert.x `WebClient` to create a client.

First, I create `BenchmarkVerticle` extends from `AbstractVerticle` and create a `WebClient` in `start` method.

```
public class BenchmarkVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> future) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

        while (true) {
             // warm up in 10s and benchmark in 20s by sending requests
             client.post(Server.port, "localhost", "/api")
                   .send(ar -> { 
                        // do something after receiving response
                   });      
        }
    }
}
```

And then I deploy `BenchmarkVerticle` in `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
    options.setBlockedThreadCheckInterval(1000*60*60); // make BlockedThreadChecker not show
    options.setWorkerPoolSize(40);
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);

    DeploymentOptions doptions = new DeploymentOptions()
            .setWorker(true);

    vertx.deployVerticle(new BenchmarkVerticle(), doptions);
}
```

I find that request are only sent when `start` method finished. I think each request is put in a queue to execute after method `start` complete. It affects to my benchmark result. I try using multithreading by `setMultiThreaded(true)` in `DeploymentOptions` object to make it send concurrently but it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use HttpClient in a multi-threaded worker verticle
```

So how to make request send immediately in WebClient?
NOTE: English is not my native language. I will expain more detailed if you feel hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i understand the setup. `BenchmarkVerticle` seems useless, unless it has more logic that you haven't revealed to in your post.

- if `BenchmarkVerticle` is responsible for handing requests

  - remove the `WebClient` references from this class
  - be sure to call `future.complete()` at the end of the body of `start()`
- ...otherwise just remove it

then...

in the class that has the `main()` method

- create the `WebClient` here
- then deploy whatever Verticle(s) you need for your testing using the overloaded version of `deployVerticle` that allows your to supply a completionHandler:

> deployVerticle(String name, DeploymentOptions options,
>   Handler> completionHandler)

the completion handler is called when your Verticle(s) are finally deployed. add your request + response handling inside this handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did it.